# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a derivative at one point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:[-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in $[-1, 1] \setminus \{0\}$. Consider the following condition: The left and right limits of $f'(x)$ at $0$ exist and are finite and equal.

a. Show, through examples, that the condition is not sufficient nor necessary for the existence of $f'(0)$.

b. Add the condition.

This exercise reminded me of the definition of a point of discontinuity of the third kind but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Ok, after the edit then for one case, consider a linear function with the same slope as it approaches $0$ from either side - but it has a jump discontinuity.  For the other direction, consider $x^2 \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as before.

Still not sure what you mean for part (b) tho.  It's just asking for another condition you can add on?  Continuity is good enough, though that's a bit trivial.

Comment: Another condition that guarantees the existence of $f'(0)\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: How about continuity at $0$?

Comment: $f'(0)$ for $x^2\sin{(1/x)}$ doesn't exist, so I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

$a.$ Take $f(x) =x \mbox{ for } x>0$ and $f(x) =x+1 \mbox{ for } x\leq 0$

$b.$ If we add that $f$ is continuous then $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: There is also a necessity aspect of their question, just a note.

Comment: Sorry I wrote it incomplete. The condition already says that they are equal

Comment: I think you have misread the question. See the comments on the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! This is the sufficient part, and the necessary one?

Comment: It is also a necessary since if $f$ is differtiable at $0$ then it is continuous at $0.$

Comment: I talked about an example that shows that the condition isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

a. Not sufficient:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \neq 0, \\ 1 & x = 0. \end{cases}$$

Not necessary:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin(1/x) & x \neq 0, \\ 0 & x = 0. \end{cases}$$
Note that $f$ is indeed differentiable at $0$, as can be seen by computing $f'(0)$ using the first principles. However, $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)$ does not exist. (Neither does the other side limit.)

b. Requiring continuity at $0$ gives us differentiability.
The proof is essentially a use of the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). For each $x > 0$, there exists $c_x \in (0, x)$ such that
$$\dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = f'(c_x).$$
Conclude from the above that
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{y \to 0^+} f'(y).$$
The right hand side is given to exist. Similarly, you get a similar equality for the left hand limit. Conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a doubt: the derivative at one point can exist when the function is not differentiable at that point?  http://calvino.polito.it/~rolando/1314An1sld_derivate.pdf Here it says that it is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: @VeronicaB the existence of derivative at point is equivalent (by definition) to the function being differentiable at that point. The function in the document that you link is different from the function that I've written. I have a square here while they don't.

Comment: I will reflect about it, thank you!